# Why does the regex (.*?(?: *?\n)) capture newlines?

Tags: python, regex

Consider the text below:

```
foobar¬
nextline
```

The regex `(.*?(?: *?\n))` matches `foobar¬`
where `¬` denotes a newline \n.

Why does the regex match it? shouldn't the non-capture group exclude it?

Tested on [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/fV8nM5) for the python dialect.

Comment: Non-capture group doesn't group, but does match.

Comment: You asked the regex engine to match it with `\n`.

Comment: the `\n` is in a non-capture group though, why is it captured?

Comment: The outer `()` is a *capture group*, that group *captures* the newline. I suspect you need `.+(?=\n)` or `(?m)^.*$(?=\n)`

Comment: [updated regex](https://regex101.com/r/fV8nM5/3) with just what you want to capture as the capturing group...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

“Non-capturing group” refers to the fact that matches within that group will not be available as separate groups in the resulting match object. For example:

```
>>> re.search('(foo)(bar)', 'foobarbaz').groups()
('foo', 'bar')
>>> re.search('(foo)(?:bar)', 'foobarbaz').groups()
('foo',)
```

However, everything that is part of an expression is *matched* and as such appears in the resulting match (Group 0 shows the whole match):

```
>>> re.search('(foo)(bar)', 'foobarbaz').group(0)
'foobar'
>>> re.search('(foo)(?:bar)', 'foobarbaz').group(0)
'foobar'
```

If you don’t want to match that part but still want to make sure it’s there, you can use a lookahead expression:

```
>>> re.search('(foo)(?=bar)', 'foobarbaz')
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 3), match='foo'>
>>> re.search('(foo)(?=bar)', 'foobaz')
None
```

So in your case, you could use `(.*?(?= *?\n))`.

Comment: That makes sense! Thanks

Comment: The lookahead itself will not match anything, it will just make sure that what’s inside comes after the expression. So if you want to match both `foo` and `bar`, you would actually need to include the newline that comes between them in the match. Since the expression will not match the newline, the match will only extend right before it, so only `foo` is matched.

Answer (score 2):

The `\n` is captured because the non-capturing group is **inside** the capturing group:

```
>>> s = 'foobar\nnextline'
>>> re.search(r'(.*?(?: *?\n))', s).groups()
('foobar\n',)
```

If you don't want that, place the non-capturing group **outside** of the capturing one:

```
>>> re.search(r'(.*?)(?: *?\n)', s).groups()
('foobar',)
```

Comment: You can even get rid of the non capturing group : `re.search(r'(.*?) *?\n', s).groups()` should give the same result.